# p:selectOneMenu is disabled with primefaces 7 integrated on SB Admin template

Tags: bootstrap-modal, primefaces-7.0

I integrated [SB Admin template](https://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin/) on my jsf project

All is worked fine with primeaces 6.

However, I got a problem after upgrading to primefaces 7.
the `p:selectOneMenu` becames disabled.

I got that exception:

[image]

I deleted `jQuery.escapeSelector = Sizzle.escape;` from `jquery.js`.

[image]

But the problem persists

Could you please tell me what I missed ?, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no need by putting both `primefeces` folder and `vendor>jquery`

you can try that architecture:

[image]

HTH